# How can I toggle the visibility of a picture based on a checkbox state?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

If the user checks the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Door"
```

I want to show a picture with the `picture_door` id. Once unchecked, I need to hide it.

I can only use HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementByValue("Door");
  var img = document.getElementById("picture_door");

  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    img.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    img.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Door" onclick="myFunction()">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Adam, this looks like valid html and javascript to me. The only thing missing is a <img id="picture_door" /> are you sure this isn't working for you? If not check your console for errors. I do recommend to use getElementById instead of getElementByValue and change value="Door" to id="Door"

Comment: There is no `document.getElementByValue`. Try adding an `id` to the checkbox and use `getElementById` or find the element another way.

Comment: You can try and pass an argument to your function (`this`, or `event`), and within your function remove the need to query the DOM for the specific element. You would then use `if(this.checked) { ... }` or `if(event.target.checked) {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```js
let img = document.getElementById("picture_door");
let door = document.getElementById("door");

img.src = "";

function myFunction(){
  if(door.checked){
    img.src = "https://i.ibb.co/mHscrNh/cat.webp";
  } else{
    img.src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Door" id="door" onclick="myFunction()">
</div>

<br>
<img src="" id="picture_door" width="120px"/>
```

Instead of using CSS, you can also unset the `src` attribute of `img` using JavaScript to hide the image.

Answer (score 0):

There is no selector called getByElementValue. You should use getElementById

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("Door");
  var label = document.getElementById("label");
  var img = document.getElementById("picture_door");

  if (!checkBox.checked){
    img.style.display = "block";
    label.innerText = "Show"
  } else {
    img.style.display = "none";
    label.innerText = "Close"
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  id="Door" onclick="myFunction()" >
<label for="Door" id="label"> Toogle </label>


<img id="picture_door" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9604813/pexels-photo-9604813.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1">
```